# Problem about a property of dilatation in Lebesgue measure

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, elementary-set-theory

I need to prove this **problem**:

> **Problem:** Prove that $$\forall \alpha \in \mathbb{R}, \forall E \in \mathfrak{M}_{\mu}(\mathbb{R}): \mu(\alpha E)=|\alpha|\mu(E)$$

> **Definition $1$:** $$E \subseteq \mathbb{R} \quad \text{is measurable Lebesgue} \quad \iff \forall \epsilon>0, \exists G \quad \text{abierto}: E\subseteq G \quad \wedge \quad  \mu^{*}(G\setminus E)\leq \epsilon $$

> **Definition $2$:** $$\mathfrak{M}_{\mu}(\mathbb{R})=\{E \subseteq \mathbb{R}: E \quad \text{measurable Lebesgue $\mu$}\}$$

> **Notation:** Here $\mu^{*}$ denote **outer measurable** and $\mu$ denote **measurable Lebesgue**.

**My attempt:** First, we need to prove that $\alpha E$ is measurable Lebesgue. For that, we need to considerer two cases:

1. $\alpha=0$.
   **Proof:**
   Let $\alpha=0$ and $E\in \mathfrak{M}_{\mu}(\mathbb{R})$, so we can see by definition that $$0E=\{0\cdot x: x\in E\}=\{0\}\in \mathfrak{M}_{\mu}(\mathbb{R}).$$
2. $\alpha\not=0$.
   **Proof:**
   Let $\alpha\not=0$ and $E \in \mathfrak{M}_{\mu}(\mathbb{R})$, we can prove that that $$\alpha E=\{\alpha \cdot E: x\in E\} \in \mathfrak{M}_{\mu}(\mathbb{R})$$but, $\alpha E$ is measurable Lebesgue if, and only if, $\forall \epsilon>0$, we can prove that there exists a open set $G$ such that $$\alpha E\subseteq G \quad \wedge \quad \mu^{*}(G\setminus \alpha E)\leq \epsilon$$
   **First question:** How can I prove this part?

*If I suppose that $\alpha E$ is measurable Lebesgue*, so we to prove that $$\forall \alpha \in \mathbb{R}, \forall E \in \mathfrak{M}_{\mu}(\mathbb{R}): \mu(\alpha E)=|\alpha|E$$
**My attempt:** Let $E\in \mathfrak{M}_{\mu}(\mathbb{R})$ and let $\alpha=0$, so we have that $$\mu(0E)=\mu(\{0\})=|0|\mu(E)$$
Now, if $\alpha\not=0$ we need to prove that $\mu(\alpha E)=|\alpha|\mu(E)$
**Second question:** How can I prove this part?

Comment: Prove it for intervals first and then use the definition of outer measure.

Comment: @copper.hat If I prove this problem to *outer meausure* $\mu^{*}$ so, can I conclude that the same to Lebesgue meausre $\mu$? Sorry, I didn't understand your hint. I'm starting with measure theory. I'm just getting started with troubleshooting this area.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3820635/27978 for example.